# Efficiency of a linked list partitioning algorithm

Tags: c++, performance, linked-list

I have come across a fun puzzle, sorting a linked list, and I wanted to go for quicksort. However, I am not quite sure whether my partitioning algorithm is efficient enough. I also believe that my code is not clean.

Is it possible to remove some variables or make it more efficient?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void printList(Node *list)
{
    Node *temp = list;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int partition(Node *list, int start, int end)
{
    Node *startPtr = list, *endPtr = list, *head = list;

    for(int i = 0; i < start; i++)
        if(startPtr == NULL || startPtr->next == NULL)
            return -1;
        startPtr = startPtr->next;

    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(endPtr == NULL || endPtr->next == NULL)
            return -1;
        endPtr = endPtr->next;
    }


    Node *temp = NULL, *temp2 = startPtr;
    int pivot = endPtr->data;

    while(temp2->next != endPtr)
    {
        if(temp2->data < pivot)
        {
            if(temp != NULL)
                temp = temp->next;
            else
                temp = startPtr;

            swap(temp->data, temp2->data);
        }
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
    swap(temp->data, endPtr->data);

    int index;
    Node *temp3 = list;

    for(index = 0; temp3->data != pivot; index++)
        temp3 = temp3->next;

    return index;
}

int main()
{
    Node *a = new Node;
    Node *b = new Node;
    Node *c = new Node;
    Node *d = new Node;
    Node *e = new Node;
    Node *f = new Node;

    a->next = b;
    a->data = 2;
    b->next = c;
    b->data = 6;
    c->next = d;
    c->data = 3;
    d->next = e;
    d->data = 1;
    e->next = f;
    e->data = 7;
    f->data = 5;

    cout<<partition(a, 0, 5)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please look at your code again? For me it looks like as if you forgot brackets in the first `for` loop in the function `partition`.

Comment: I recommend fixing the indentation. That makes the code a lot more pleasant to read.

Comment: Please add a statement of the exact puzzle.  Reading your code doesn't make it clear to me. Running it just prints '3'. And `printList` is unused...

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you're missing brackets, but I think I get what you're trying to do. If I'm wrong, ignore this obviously.

`printList` can just use a `for`-loop:

```
void printList(Node *list)
{

 for(Node *temp = list; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next;)
 {
    cout<<temp->data<<" ";
 }
}
```

Now for the partition function, you're always returning `-1` if `startPtr == NULL` or `endPtr == NULL`. But you say that those point to what list points to (at the start of the function). In that case, just check if list is null first. Your function won't do anything if it is anyway:

```
if(list == NULL)
   return -1;
```

Now in those `for`-loops, all you have to do is check if `startPtr->next` and `endPtr->next == NULL`.

In your `while` loop, you have this code:

```
if(temp2->data < pivot)
{
    if(temp != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;
    else
        temp = startPtr;

    swap(temp->data, temp2->data);
}
```

But what if, for example, `temp == NULL` and `temp2 == startPtr`? Assuming `swap()` does what it says it does, you're unnecessarily swapping values. It might be expensive, and it might not be. I dunno. The function might also do something weird if you try to swap the same exact values. (As a side note,  you're just passing the value of data. If swap doesn't take values by reference, you won't actually be doing anything to `temp->data` and `temp2->data`).

Also, in the declaration of your `while` loop, you're not checking for if `temp2 == NULL`.

```
while(temp2->next != endPtr) //This is will throw a Null Pointer Access Violation exception if temp2 == NULL
```

This could happen, because you aren't checking if `temp2->next == NULL` before you say `temp2 = temp2->next`. If it ever is, your loop will crash the program. I don't know if it's possible for `temp2` to reach the end of the list, but if it is, you should just add a conditional.

After your `while`-loop, you have:

```
temp = temp->next;
swap(temp->data, endPtr->data);
```

That could potentially cause the same problems I described before.

Anyway, these are just suggestions. I didn't check thoroughly to see if there were variables you could remove, though.